# Inline blocks not aligning properly

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have a problem with three divs that should align so that two divs (**div1** and **div2**) are on the left and one div (**div3**, that's as tall as combined div1 and div2) is on the right. I am not sure how to resolve it and I wouldn't like to use floats, as the third div should be just next to those two divs, not jsut floated to the right.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="test1">
</div>
<div class="test3">
</div>
<div class="test2">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:260px;
}

.test1 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.test2 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.test3 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etekiller/Lmntv6am/1/)

Could you please help me with this? It can be done with a different technique, but those elements have to stick together, not just be floated, because when I make it responsive then floated elements will separate.

Comment: If the third should also be right next to the 2 divs why not float all of them to the left. I mean the semantic purpose of the float is to do this right?

Comment: Because then the div3 gets between div1 and div2. Even when all three are floated.

Comment: One more thing that could possibly be the reason is that your container is not big enough to accomodate all the three divs. Total width of divs is 450px where your container has only 260px. Try increasing the width to 500px.

Comment: Well then they will be in one line. Div1 and div2 have to be on separate lines, whereas div3 has to be as tall as both of these lines and to the right of div1 and div2.

Comment: You wouldn't like to use floats, but describe your problem with floated :/ Why you do not want to use floats for something the floats are actually made? Using `margin-top: -50px`, like its suggested is only for a short duration a solution, now try to make it responsive and have more problems because of the `margin-top` than the floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  position property

```
.test1
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
.test2
{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
}
.test3
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:200px;
width:50px;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**
Dont Forget to set its parent position relative

```
.container {
width:260px;
position:relative;
margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but absolute positioning will not work here, as there is an image to the left of those two divs. It will make them disappear behind that image.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I can't post the DOM from my project because it's classified.

Comment: Okey try this.. add inline-block property to both image and the container containing those three blocks

Comment: I will try as soon as I'm done with one thing today and I will come back here and update you whether it works. If it works I will select your answer as the best :).

Comment: @Pe-Ter of course ... i tried it.. it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: you will have to add 'vertical-align:top' also.. here is the working fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/reenleedr/Lmntv6am/8/

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had technical problems. I've selected your answer as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="test1">
</div>
<div class="test3">
</div>
<div class="test2">
</div>
</div>
<style>
.test2 {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
.test1 {
display: inline-block;
width: 196px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
.test3 {
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with negative margin-bottom for div3 and vertical-align: middle for other divs ?

Just add

```
margin-bottom: -50px;
```

My code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmntv6am/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
.test3 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:black;
        margin-bottom: -50%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyfryc2j/

Maybe you can also use "position: absolute", if the sizes are fixed:

```
.container {
    position: relative; width: 250px; height: 100px;
}
.test1 {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.test2 {
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.test3 {
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmg4ek3j/1/

You can also use floats for your purpose:

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
}
.test1 {
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.test2 {
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.test3 {
    float: right;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjwg6w9h/1/